# JQUERY Donation for paypal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, paypal

Hello stackOverflow community!,

This might be a lot to ask but I'm trying to make a donation box, where the user is able to select a donation amount or write their amount. Once the confirm button is clicked it will direct the user to the payPal page with the amount set on the page. Would anyone be able to guide me in the right direction? I'm good at HTML and CSS (currently learning JQUERY and PHP).

I got the inspiration from this website - http://www.losttype.com/font/?name=liberator

Many thanks

Comment: Can you add your work-in-progress implementation to the question?

Comment: Hello, heres my code - https://jsfiddle.net/8rcybfxa/

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Any idea on how I would transfer the amount to paypal?

Answer (score 1):

PayPal has a guide on [Create a Donate Button](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/get-started/donate-button). You can also take a look at this document: [How to Add a Donate Button to a Page Using PayPal Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/ht_pps-donateButton/).

Comment: That anchor is broken, use this one instead: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/ht_pps-donateButton/